# Unable to receive push notifications from Pushwoosh to TestFlight distributed app

Tags: ios, xcode, configuration, push-notification, pushwoosh

I am able to receive push notifications on a device that is registered as a test device however I am unable to receive any push notifications from a build distributed via TestFlight.

Below are the steps I took during testing and deployment of a build for TestFlight. Any assistance in pointing out the flaw would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

=======

- Configured the app to use the development *.cer and *.p12 files.
- iPhone that is configured to be a test device.
- Compile my app (from Xcode) on my test device and receive a test push notification.
- Disconnect the device (from Xcode) and receive a test push notification.
- Successfully receive a regular **(not test!)** push notification from the same compiled app.
- Delete the device from the list of test devices and send a regular push notification and receive it just fine.
- Archive the app for TestFlight which requires the Distribution
  Provisioning Profiles to be used (Verified during validation that they were mapped/using the correct ones.)
- Attempt to send a push notification, receive an error that ther is an 'Invalid token'. [screenshot - invalid token](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/119454/Untitled%2012.png)
- Change the *.cer and *.p12 files to the distribution files.
- Attempt test push notification and receive nothing. No invalid
  token, however zero devices are now "push available". [screenshot - zero devices](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/119454/Untitled%2015.png)
- Also, no 'report' from the push history.

What am I not configuring properly?

Again, thanks for any help.

Comment: After archiving, have you tried sending both a regular (production) and test (development) push notification, while making no changes in between attempts?

Comment: @MikeTaverne: Yep, did those tests 2x without success. I did, however, come in the next morning and connected the same device to my machine to get the log files at Pushwoosh's request and, embarrasingly (?), the development push notification came through.

Comment: @MikeTaverne: Go figure. I'd asked if there was some sort of propagation that occurs when changing the *.cer and *.p12 files to which they responded 'no, should work right away'. Chalking this one up to ghost in the machine.

Answer (score 0):

After you change the certificate you have to resubscribe the devices as they were removed from the database by the last "invalid token" push.